# Integrability of mean value function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm consider a one-dimensional function $u\in L^1(I)$ where $I$ is a bounded open interval. I first extend $u$ to zero outside $I$. Then I take a small parameter $\epsilon>0$ and define
$$u_{\epsilon}(t)=\frac{\int_{t-\epsilon}^{t}u(s)ds}{\epsilon}.$$
By the integrability of $u$, I know that every point $t\in I$ is a Lebesgue point so $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0}u_{\epsilon}(t)=u(t)$ for a.e. $t\in I$. But I would like to know if $u_{\epsilon}$ can keep the integrability of $u$ i.e. whether $u_{\epsilon}\in L^1(I)$?
If it can keep this, can we pass to higher dimension?

Add what I tried: to show the integrability is actually to calculate that
\begin{align*}
\int_{I}|u_{\epsilon}(t)|dt&\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{I}\int_{t-\epsilon}^{t}|u(s)|dsdt\\
&\leq\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{I}\int_{I}|u(s)|dsdt\\
&=\frac{|I|}{\epsilon}\cdot\lVert u\rVert_{1}<\infty.
\end{align*}
So I guess it can keep the integrability. Does it make sense?

Comment: Interesting, but what did you try? [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauval, thank you for pointing this out and I added what I have tried. Would this be a little better?

Comment: Yes,  i guess you are correct iff the ratio $\frac{I}{\epsilon}$ is finite for every sufficiently small enough $\epsilon$.According to your definition of lebesgue point.

Comment: Yes Emiya you are correct. With a little more care, you can even prove that $\|u_\varepsilon\|_1\le\|u\|_1.$

Comment: @AnneBauval, thank you, but may I ask why? Because what I have tried is kind of like change the integral domain from parallelogram to the whole rectangle, which has increased the area. So how should I change without adding more area?

Comment: $t-\epsilon<s<t$ so when you change the order of integration (by Fubini), $s<t<s+\epsilon$ instead of $t\in I.$

Comment: @AnneBauval, thank you very much and one more last question. If I change $L^1$ to general $L^p$, then $u_{\epsilon}\in L^p(I)$, but I guess we do not have $\lVert u_{\epsilon}\rVert_p \leq \lVert u\rVert_p$ any more.  Instead, we only have $\lVert u_{\epsilon}\rVert_p \leq \epsilon^{p-1}\cdot\lVert u\rVert_p$, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, but maybe [Minkowski's integral inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski's_integral_inequality) could help.

Comment: See the Hardy-Littlewood maximal inequality. Your proof is correct and be generalized to higher dimensions, but HL says you can get a bound independent of $\epsilon$.